# accessing script parameter from bash function without passing them on call

Tags: bash, bash-function

Is there any way to access bash script parameters from script function if the function is not explicitly called with script parameters?

Thanks.

Comment: I think you'll need to elaborate on this to clarify your question. Can you give an example?

Comment: Why do you want to do this? What are you trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, but you can hack it if you are on Linux by reading your script's command-line from `/proc':

```
function myfunc {

    while read -d $'\0' 
    do 
        echo "$REPLY"
    done < /proc/$$/cmdline
}
```

The `-d $'\0'` is required to read the cmdline file because the strings are NULL (binary zero) delimited.  In the example, `$REPLY` will be each parameter in turn, including bash itself.  For example:

```
/home/user1> ./gash.sh one two three
/bin/bash
./gash.sh
one
two
three
```

Here is an example which will set the function's parameters to those of the script (and display them):

```
function myfunc {

    while read -d $'\0' 
    do
        args="$args $REPLY"
    done < /proc/$$/cmdline

    set -- $args
    shift 2      # Loose the program and script name
    echo "$@"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is "No, not that I know of."

If it had to be done I'd alias the script arguments.

```
#!/bin/bash
script_args=("$@")
myfunc () {
    for a in "$@" ; do
        for b in "${script_args[@]}" ; do
            echo "$a: $b"
        done
    done
}

myfunc one two
```

And then call like this:

```
./myscript.sh 1 2
```

Output:

```
one: 1
one: 2
two: 1
two: 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Just call the function with the script's arguments.

```
foo () {
    for arg in "$@"
    do
        echo "$arg"
    done
}

foo "$@"
```